# How to use TAR for directory range?

Tags: bash, unix, tar

I have a lot of dirs like:

```
    /dir/1/
    /dir/2/
    ...
    /dir/1200/
```

I need to tar directories by range 0-999, 1000-1999, 2000-2999 into d0.tar.bz2, d1.tar.bz2, d2.tar.bz2 and etc.

I wrote this script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for i in {0..10}
    do
            let "tt = ($i+1)*1000"
            let "ff = $i*1000"
            tar -cfv /backups/d$i.tar.bz2 /dir/{$ff..$tt}
    done
```

But I have errors while running:

```
    tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
    tar: /backups/d0.tar.bz2: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
    tar: /dir/{0..1000}: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
    tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

[Brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) happens before variable expansion, saying:

```
... /dir/{$ff..$tt}
```

would not work.

A workaround might be to use an array and [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
range=($(seq $ff $tt))
... "${range[@]/#//dir/}"
```

Comment: Great solution, but I have: `tar: /backups/d0.tar.bz2: Cannot stat: No such file or directory`

Comment: Ok, I have found error, I should do `-cvf /backups/d$i.tar.bz2` instead of `-cfv /backups/d$i.tar.bz2`